# Generate equidistant multidimensional vectors as Embedding matrix

Tags: python, tensorflow, vector, keras, embedding

I need to generate an embedding matrix to use instead of the layer. I know a priori the similarity between the 10 features (all equidistant from each other) and I can't generate the matrices through training because I don't have enough data.

To do this I have to generate 10 vectors of arbitrary size (ie 10) but which all have the same size and which are all equidistant from each other, with values of the single dimensions being numbers between -1 and 1, all this in python.

Anyone know how this can be done?